# Globalising fibrations by schedules

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology

In a paper in Fund Math 130.2 (1988): 125-136. http://eudml.org/doc/211719 Dyer and Eilenberg give an account of the local-global theorem for fibrations by proving a "Schedule Theorem"  that, given a numerable cover $\mathcal U $ of a space $X$, "it is  possible to continuously decompose each path in $X$ into subpaths such that each subpath lies in a prescribed set of the cover". From this they easily deduce 
the well known globalisation theorem,  first stated by Hurewicz and later developed by Dold and others, which is a foundation for the theory of fibrations.

**Question:** Is it possible to extend this theorem to higher dimensions replacing paths by cubes $I^n$ and by constructing a corresponding space of schedules of cubes? In particular for $n=2$?

This is phrased for cubes rather than simplices since cubes have a  clear notion of multiple composition.